# position of cell penetrating peptide

Tags: proteins, protein-folding

I'd like to add a cell penetrating peptide to my custom peptide (30aa). Can I just add it to the end of the peptide sequence or does it have to be positioned on an outward facing external chain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This papers tables shows that cell penetrating peptides are placed before their cargo peptide and do not need to be on a side chain.
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1576229/table/tbl1/